# Find all songs from albums from a particular genre?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Effectively the basic models are defined like this:

```
class Song    
  belongs_to :album  
end

class Album  
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy  
  belongs_to :genre  
end
```

Now I want to find all the songs from albums of say genre_id=10, how can I do that?

`.songs` association only works on a single Album object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `has_many :through` association. Check [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) for details.

In your case, all you need to do is to define `Genre` class like this:

```
class Genre
  has_many :albums
  has_many :songs, through: :albums
end
```

Then you can call `songs` on `Genre` object:

```
Genre.find(10).songs
```

### EDIT

If you want more that one kind of associations between Genres and Songs, here is a workaround:

```
class Genre
  has_many :albums
  has_many :artists
  has_many :album_songs, through: :albums, source: :song
  has_many :artist_songs, through: :artists, source: :song
end
```

This enables you to write:

```
Genre.find(10).album_songs
Genre.find(10).artist_songs
```

May looks a little weird, but it's up to you to give them appropriate names.

Comment: What if I have a relationship has_many :songs, through: artists present in the model. Now Genre.find would not  fetch from albums.

Comment: @user2186138 Well, that's a wierd situation. Maybe you can use different name for each relation. See my edit. It's not ideal, but works.